# Javascript TypeMismatchError when reading file in IE only

Tags: javascript

I am reading in a text file uploaded by the user in the browser.  The code works as intended in Chrome and Firefox, however in IE I get a TypeMismatchError although the code continues to execute normally (reads just fine and doesn't crash.)  The error is on the following call: read.readAsText(inFile);

I am using a button to initiate the upload request instead of the standard file input div; so clicking the button causes a click on the file input div and after the user selects a file, I handle the upload.

```html
    <!-- Hidden Divs -->
    <input type="file" name="my_file" id="my-file" style="display: none">
```

```
    // Open Set button on main page
    $("#open-set").click(function () {
        // Clear file name already there (in case we try to upload the same file)
        $('#my-file').val("");
        // Actual file selector is hidden, so fake click
        $('#my-file').click();
    });

    // Click handler
    $('#my-file').on('change', function(){
        handleFiles(this.files);
    });

    // handles incoming file from open-set
    handleFiles = function (files) {
        var inFile = files[0];
        //console.log(inFile);
        read = new FileReader();
        read.readAsText(inFile);  << ERROR ON THIS LINE

        // When file is ready, load as json
        read.onloadend = function () {
            var userData = JSON.parse(read.result);
            // render each json object to table
            for (var i = 0; i < userData.length; i++) {
                renderTableBody(userData[i]);
            }
        }
    }
```

As I said, the code works, and I cant detect any misbehavior even after the error is thrown, but I don't want to leave any errors in my console.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does the error name a line?

Comment: Sorry, yes - the error is on read.readAsText(inFile);  I updated the code to show where it is